# timeoutWith operator Angular 5 Httpcleint

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

just startting to upgrade angular 2.0.0 to 5.2.0 . So i'm using HttpClient . 
I want to use timeoutWith operator on `httpClient.get()`. All i get is  `Property 'timeoutWith' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

```
someFunction(){
 let someUrl = '.../../' ;
return this._httpClient.get(url).timeoutWith(1000,this.throwTimeout()).catch(this.handleError);

}
```

What am i doing wrong ? this was working with the previous httpmodule

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith';
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i added it in the service but it was still the same. Later on i imported it in app.module.ts. Now things are fine .

Answer (score 1):

A lot of properties doesn't exist anymore on type Observable, now.

You need to import that from rxjs.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith';
```

You should probably import other properties like map

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

This [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1213737/Upgrade-to-Angular-and-HttpClient) could help you to migrate from Angular 2 to Angular 5.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, You should import you observable operators individually.
It's goes with the guide lines of angular and their [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) compile.
Splitting your imports help's the compiler to do [tree shaking](http://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/).

So, as other already wrote, You need to add timeoutWith operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith';
```

And any other operator you need to use.

Comment: So in every service i've to import map , catch and other operators ? or is it fine if i import it in app.module.ts file ?

Comment: In every service you use them you need to import them.. You can read more about it in here : https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-rxjs-imports/